# Flutter: dynamically add tabs and keep state with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

Tags: tabs, dart, flutter, state

I'm trying to create a form with tabs. In each tab I have TextFormField. Tabs have AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to keep their State. Tabs can be created dynamically.  When new tab is created, it is inserted in the middle of the tabs list.

Problem: when new tab is inserted, its TextFormField keep state of the next tab and so on. It seems states keeps in order from 1 to n. Is there any way to keep the right state for tabs?

Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabTesting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabTestingState createState() => _TabTestingState();
}

class _TabTestingState extends State<TabTesting> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  List<MyTab> _tabs = [
      MyTab(TabData("1", "1")),
      MyTab(TabData("3", "3")),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: _tabs.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TabTesting"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          tabs: _tabs.map((tab) => Text(tab.tabData.name)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _tabs,
        ),
      ),
      persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Add tab"),
          onPressed: () {
            final newTab = MyTab(TabData("2", "2"));
            final newTabs = _tabs;
            newTabs.insert(1, newTab);
            final index = _tabController.index;
            setState(() {
              _tabs = newTabs;             
              _tabController = TabController(
                  vsync: this,
                  length: newTabs.length,
                  initialIndex: index);
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyTab extends StatefulWidget {

  final tabData;

  MyTab(this.tabData);

  @override
  _MyTabState createState() => _MyTabState();
}

class _MyTabState extends State<MyTab> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tab(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: widget.tabData.name),
        initialValue: widget.tabData.data,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabData {
  String name;
  String data;

  TabData(this.name, this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add `super.build(context);` as the [documentation of AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) suggests.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Tab(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: widget.tabData.name),
        initialValue: widget.tabData.data,
      ),
    );
  }
```